# onblur event is not working for lightning-input-field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

```
    <lightning-record-view-form object-api-name='Opportunity' record-id='0065j00000W8wwvAAB'>
        <lightning-input-field field-name='AccountId' onblur={lossFocus}> 
        </lightning-input-field>
    </lightning-record-view-form>
```

Will never call {lossFocus} method when lightning-input-field loss focus. Can anyone help me on find a way to call this JS function?

Comment: Hey @Jay I'm also facing this issue, were you able to solve this?